# In SQL, how do I check what are the data in a categorical attribute?

Tags: sql

For example, in a table, I have an attribute call "color", how to check what unique colors are included in the "color" attribute?

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | red |
| Ben | blue |

Looking for a result that looks like: red, blue, green, black

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you select the unique values of the column

```
select distinct color from yourtable
```

Or you group by the column

```
select color, count(*) as total
from yourtable
group by color
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` to return only different values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM table_name;
```